# Can anyone tell me what is the name of this widget?

Tags: user-interface, android

Does anyone know what is the widget used ? I know there's an ActionBar tab, but this doesn't look like a tab view either from the examples I've seen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is viewpager. Here is the link - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html